# This code isn't working & is their a more efficient way to do this rather than using a else if statement?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm new to all this, i have a project for college, can't seem to get this to work and it seems to have a lot of repeating code, any help would be great, thanks.

```
var strength = document.getElementById('getstren');
strength.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 17) + 1);

    if (strength == 1) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "-5"

    }else if (strength == 2 || strength == 3) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "-4"

    }else if (strength == 4 || strength == 5) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "-3" 

    }else if (strength == 6 || strength == 7) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "-2"
    }
    else if (strength == 8 || strength == 9) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "-1"
    }
    else if (strength == 10 || strength == 11) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "0"      
    }
    else if (strength == 12 || strength == 13) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "1"
    }
    else if (strength == 14 || strength == 15) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "2"  
    }
    else if (strength == 16 || strength == 17) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "3"
    }
    else if (strength == 18) {
        document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = "4"
    }
```

I think it should display a figure for strength and should display another figure for athletics depending on the first figure!

Comment: `strength` is a HTMLElement, not an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to access the `innerHTML` of `strength` and use `parseInt` to make it an integer. Secondly, you can use the following statement to make your code simpler: `document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = Math.floor(strength / 2) - 5`.

```
var strength = document.getElementById('getstren');
strength.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 17) + 1);
document.getElementById('ath').innerHTML = Math.floor(parseInt(strength) / 2) - 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `strength` is a [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). Therefore, it will never be equal to an integer.

To access the html of the HTMLElement, you can use the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property which returns a string. You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to cast it to an integer.

Example:

```
// Assumes strength is defined

const strengthInt = parseInt(strength.innerHTML)

if(strength == 1){
  // Set ath html
}
//Other if-else here
```

As for an alternative to if-else, look at [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).